# How to update custom user meta field in wp?

Tags: php, wordpress

I use the following to add and display new user meta fields on the user profile editor screen but when I click the update button, the values don't change:

```
  function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
    <table class="form-table">
      <tr>
          <th><label for="save_post_external"><?php _e("Save posts external"); ?></label></th>
          <td>
              <input type="text" name="save_post_external" id="save_post_external" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'save_post_external', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th><label for="save_post_internal"><?php _e("Save posts internal"); ?></label></th>
          <td>
              <input type="text" name="save_post_internal" id="save_post_internal" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'save_post_internal', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
          </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  <?php }
  add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
  add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );


  add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
  add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

  function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { 
      return false; 
    }
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'Save Posts', $_POST['save_post_external'] );
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'Save Posts', $_POST['save_post_internal'] );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is fine just need to fix two lines. You just missed the correct userMeta name.

```
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post_external', $_POST['save_post_external'] );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post_internal', $_POST['save_post_internal'] );
```

Also, here is working code:

```
function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
        <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="save_post_external"><?php _e("Save posts external"); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="save_post_external" id="save_post_external" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'save_post_external', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="save_post_internal"><?php _e("Save posts internal"); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="save_post_internal" id="save_post_internal" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'save_post_internal', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <?php }
        add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
        add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );


        add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
        add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );

    function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { 
        return false; 
        }
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post_external', $_POST['save_post_external'] );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'save_post_internal', $_POST['save_post_internal'] );
    }
```

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: might we go into chat as I have one last quick question?